# Render [object Window] to HTML using ajax / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having a problem with the following function. It's rendering in the browser as  [object Window] instead of the HTML content...

BTW, the eval(func_fix); is executing InsertMenu() correctly.

Any idea why?

Thank you in advance.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#component").each(function() {
        var func = $(this).attr("name");
        var func_fix = func.replace(")",","+$(this).attr("data-pagenum")+")");

        var content = eval(func_fix);
        $(this).replaceWith("<div>" + content + "</div>");
    });
});

function InsertMenu(param,pagenum) {
$.get("compmenustructure.asp",{pagenum: pagenum, stylemenunum: param})
.done(function(data) {
    content = data;
});

return content;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read JavaScript (that is, ECMAScript 5.1) reference better.

`"<div>" + content + "</div>"` is `+` operation between string and an object, and in that case, an object is converted to its string representation by calling its `.toString()` method.

So, `content` contains the `window` object. Make it contain the string you want to include in `div` (I don't know what do you want to have there, your code is just part of page; no one can answer you unless you say what is in `name` and `data-pagenum` attributes, for example).

Comment: name = InsertMenu(7) and data-pagenum=38
I'm just tried to include a menu using ajax.
If I add an alert(content) before $(this).replaceWith("<div>" + content + "</div>"); it renders fine... but I dont want to output this alert...

Comment: You should add alert with "<div>"+... and you will see it's not correct. Not to mention the *BIG* bug: you cannot just "return content" from ajax call - it is asynchronous. You must do _everything_ (including `replaceWith`) in the `done` callback.

Comment: (and you use global variable; please put `var content` at the beginning of `insertMenu` function - though you will not need it if you do it right, that is, inside `done`, you can simple use `data`, but anyway - be careful about using globals, it's bad thing)